# How to get data from a HTML table into DJango

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-models

I'm relatively new to web development so I'm not sure that I'm taking the correct route with this. I have a web app for home buyers to submit their information (address and such). With such a purchase, you can have multiple buyers (such as you could have with a business). I've included a table and some text boxes where when filled out, a new buyer is added as a row in the table using java script. I'm not sure exactly how to get this information  back into DJango, although I have read where it might involve AJAX calls. Does anyone have any pointers?
Thank you.

Comment: I would google "django forms". Django has some built-in features that will allow you to connect a form directly to a model (which is basically the object that is mapped to the database). [Here's one tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/), but there are many others out there.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I'm using ModelForm now, but I'm not sure as to how to handle a dynamic number of items. I could make an assumption that there will only be up to 3 buyers and then just put a set of text field inputs for each user. I don't think that this would nearly be as nice as having the ability to add an indeterminate amount of into a collection. I've found some information in a link [Dynamic Forms](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2018/05/07/creating-dynamic-forms-django/), what do you think of it?

Comment: So, formsets could handle adding a dynamic number of buyers, but that still leaves me with how to handle the single property that is associated with the buyer(s). My desire is that the person filling out the form would enter the property address, and then add the buyer(s)' information where it would list them below in a table and they submit it all at once. I have two different models/ModelForms and am using a CreateView generic. I don't suppose there is a way to submit multiple types of ModelForms through a single CreateView?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I'm about to answer my own question.

I used jquery to add new buyers to a table along with delete buttons that can delete each buyer. I used an ajax call to post the address and json data for the buyers table ( `buyers = $('#buyers_table').tableToJSON();` ) back to Django.

I then went into the forms.py and over wrote clean() for my property form, cleaning the address and then parsing the self.data to grab the buyer's information and put them into the cleaned_data as a list of dictionaries.

Next, I over wrote save() for my property form, saving the cleaned address and then creating a Buyer entry for each buyer in the cleaned_data buyers list with the foreign key set to the current property.

Now I just need to go do the cleanup and add some constraints. BTW, Visual Studio 2019's debugger was a ton of help with this.